# Handling authenticated session timeouts in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a LOB Silverlight app that uses web services, and forms authentication to authenticate users. The app has a lot of state on the client side. My problem is when the client comes back to the app after a period of inactivity, and their authenticated session has expired so they get authentication errors back from the web services that require authentication.

What is the best method to prevent this situation?

I have tried using a "heartbeat" via dummy web service method that is called at a regular interval and that seems to work for keeping the session alive, but is there a better solution?

Comment: You need to have a function that sends periodical request to your server, so your session gets updated every time like _Chadit_ anwsered.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase session timeout or send regular request to service for keeping the session. Or when session is expired ask user relogin to application. I guess, it's standard practices for Web application based on ASP.NET infrastructure.

Comment: On some hosting providers you can't change the session timeout.

Answer (score 1):

This post is what I have done and it appears to accomplish what you are asking

[Preventing an ASP.NET Session Timeout when using Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066090/preventing-an-asp-net-session-timeout-when-using-silverlight)